# Адаптивный слайдер

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper, carousel

У меня 16 картинок, я хочу, чтобы при десктопной версии было 4 ряда по 4 (т.е. все картинки без слайда), а при мобильном одна картинка и листать ее, какой слайдер можно использовать или как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Для настольной версии https://swiperjs.com/demos/170-slides-per-column/core.html, устанавливаете свои значения, для моб версии https://swiperjs.com/demos#responsive-breakpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подобного существует библиотека https://swiperjs.com/. Весьма гибкая и простая в настройке. Пример проекта с ее использованием и настройкой для адаптивности: https://github.com/Sunbey13/YouTube